# Join table with Primary Key: org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Component

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "employee_id")
private Integer employeeId;

@Column(name = "doj")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date doj;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.employee")
private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProject;
//
```

Project.java

```
public class Project implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "project_id")
private Integer projectId;

@Column(name = "exp_end_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date expEndDate;

@Column(name = "project_name")
private String projectName;

@Column(name = "start_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.project")
private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProject;
```

EmployeeProject.java

```
@IdClass(EmployeeProjectPK.class)
public class EmployeeProject implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Id
@Column(name = "PROJECT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int projectId;    

@Id
@Column(name = "employee_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int employeeId;    


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
private Employee employee;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
private Project project;
```

EmployeeProjectPK.Java

```
public class EmployeeProjectPK implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer id;
private Integer projectId;
private Integer employeeId;
```

Based on above entity design, when I try to persist an 'Employee', I'm getting bellow exception. Any thought?

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Component

Comment: I think you  using @Embeddable annotation in the EmployeeProjectPK class resolves the issue. Please try and let me know

Comment: @VijayanKani [at]Embeddable and [at]EmbeddedId is just an alternative way to represent composite key so its mostly like [at]IdClass. please check this article for more info http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem in mapped by in Employee entity

can you please try using

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProject;
```

**instead of**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.employee")
private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProject;
```

Also try to change it too in Project entity and use

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "project")
private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProject;
```

**instead of**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.project")
private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProject;
```

> So finally you should replace
>
> **mappedBy = "id.project"** by **mappedBy = "project"**
>
> AND
>
> **mappedBy = "id.employee"** by **mappedBy = "employee"**

Comment: My bad! Thanks for figuring it out. That worked. Now, Im struggling with a new issue. When I try to persist 'Employee' object, ORM not inserting into the JOIN TABLE. But, I don't see any kind of exception. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @pijushcse which tables it inserting to ? and which are not ? u mean it inserts to Employee table but not inserting in these tables which have a relation with Employee or what do u mean ?